Is it possible to figure out the Steumot and Petuchot in Nach using the old style Mikraot Gedolot text?
In the old Warsaw Edition of the Mikraot Gedolot there are various indentations that would suggest there are open and closed paragraph marks in the text but these markings do not match the more modern Tanach editions or the old style Mechon-Mamre edition.
I already checked the Chumush portion of this Mikraot Gedolot and the paragraph indicators do not match.
There are comments in the margins of this text to show that there was interest in highlighting where these open and closed marks are but I cannot 100% figure out what their opinion on these marks are.
Evidence that they were highlighting this information can be found by looking at this edition on the page where you would find Yehoshua 4:1. There is a star in the middle of the sentence and a comment on the side.
Here is a link to the edition that I'm speaking of. After one clicks on the link then one must turn to page 16 to see the asterisk but also to see the other indentations that seem to indicate paragraph marks.
I have not found any book yet that concretizes this edition's opinion on the open and closed marks and would appreciate a suggestion of a book that does. Or also an opinion of whose opinion on paragraph marks would match nicely with this edition.
Link to the Warsaw edition: https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990019074530205171/NLI?volumeItem=10

which mikraot gedolot text are you using?

Warsaw 1875 edition. An electronic link to this style is: https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990019074530205171/NLI?volumeItem=10     -after you copy this link you go to pg. 16 to see a page on Yehoshua 4:1 where you can see in the comments that there's a paragraph mark in the midst of the sentence. My observation is that if they bothered to include this piece of information they are implying that their text clearly shows where the other paragraphs marks are and what type they are.

Hi MrsHan. Please do not put important info in the comments. [Edit] your question to update it and include all important info there. Remember not to just append to your question but take the opportunity to rewrite and reorganize so someone who hasn't checked the edit history finds that it flows clearly.

Well done MrsHan, thank you

In the Torah volumes it looks like it uses פ and ס marks to indicate parsha breaks but not in Nakh volumes. Before the 20th century there was no fixed tradition of parsha breaks in Nakh (as noted by the aruch hashulchan https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.283.14). If I had to guess there's a decent chance the printer didn't mark פ and ס in Nakh because he wasn't confident in the breaks he printed (either because he made them up or because didnt trust the text he copied from). Perhaps the פסקא באמצע פסוק made it in because they happened to have a masoretic note about it.

Petuchot are labelled פ and setumot are labelled ס. Shirim are indicated with breaks using the letter ש IIRC, but I'm not sure about the last one

@NoachMiFrankfurt Can you provide a citation to one such mark פ ס in the book linked by the OP?

@DoubleAA, I've never seen an edition without them, but I am away from home, where I have Warsaw editions of Yechezkel-Trei 'Asar

@Noach You can access all the volumes digitally through that link (in the Volumes drop down menu)
